# regular expression search in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to parse some data and just started reading up on regular Expressions so I am pretty new to it. This is the code I have so far

```
String = "MEASUREMENT   3835    303 Oxygen:     235.78 Saturation:      90.51 Temperature:      24.41 DPhase:      33.07 BPhase:      29.56 RPhase:       0.00 BAmp:     368.57 BPot:      18.00 RAmp:       0.00 RawTem.:           68.21"
String = String.strip('\t\x11\x13')

String = String.split("Oxygen:")
print String[1]
String[1].lstrip
print String[1]
```

What I am trying to do is to do is remove the oxygen data (235.78) and put it in its own variable using an regular expression search. I realize that there should be an easy solution but I am trying to figure out how regular expressions work and they are making my head hurt. Thanks for any help

Richard

Comment: `String` is a valid, but confusing variable name in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
string = "blabla Oxygen:      10.10 blabla"
regex_oxygen = re.compile('''Oxygen:\W+([0-9.]*)''')
result = re.findall(regex_oxygen,string)
print result
```

Answer (score 2):

```
re.search( r"Oxygen: *([\d.]+)", String ).group( 1 )
```

Comment: nit-pick: `r'Oxygen:\s*(\d+(\.\d+)?)'` is more likely to hit on unexpected input as it doesn't require space between 'Oxygen:' and the value and will accept integers as well reals. "Be liberal in what you accept" -Jon Postel

Answer (score 0):

What for?

```
print String.split()[4]
```

Comment: To make sure that I am not getting garbage for data. If there is no match I can deal with it some other way

Comment: So then make sure that element `[3]` equals `Oxygen:`.

Answer (score 0):

For general parsing of lists like this one could

```
import re
String = "MEASUREMENT   3835    303 Oxygen:     235.78 Saturation:      90.51"
String = String.replace(':','')
value_list=re.split("MEASUREMENT\W+[0-9]+\W+[0-9]+\W",String)[1].rstrip().split()
values = dict(zip(value_list[::2],map(float,value_list[1::2])))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to you specific problem has been posted. However I wanted to show you a few ressource for regular expression for python. The [python documentation on regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) is the place to start.

O'reilly also has [many good books on the subject](http://search.oreilly.com/?q=regular+expressions), either if you want to understand regular expression deep down or just enough to make things work.

Finally [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a good ressource for regular expression among mainstream languages. You can even test your regular expression on the website.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to share my ?is this an email? regex expresion, just to inspire you. :)

```
  9 emailregex = "^[a-zA-Z.a-zA-Z]+@mycompany.org$"
 10
 11 def validateEmail(email):
 12         """returns 1 if is an email, 0 if not """
 13         # len(x.y@mycompany.org) = 17
 14         if len(email)>=17:
 15                 if re.match(emailregex,email)!= None:
 16                         return 1
 17         return 0
```